# Create a dynamic multiple dropdown select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm fetching a list of objects from a database, say articles, that have a category attribute, and I'll be adding a filtering capability to my angularjs app where I can select multiple articles based on the subcategories, grouped by category

I'm trying to do as follows in my html:

```
<select multiple >
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
  <optgroup ng-repeat="category in categories" label="{{category.category}}"> 
    <option ng-repeat="subcategory in category.subcategories" value="{{subcategory}}">{{subcategory}}</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

but the categories and subcategories can be diverse and I don't want to hardcode it on my app, rather, grouping that information from all the articles I retrieve from the database, so in my Controller, in the function I use to fetch all the articles I have the following

```
function getAllArticles(){
  var promise = article.getAll();
  promise.then(function( articles ){
    $scope.articles = articles.data

    var result = $scope.articles.map(function(a) {return a.category.category;});
    var res = arrayUnique(result);

    for(var i = 0; i < res.length; i++){
      $scope.categories[i] = {'category': res[i] }

      var result2 = $scope.articles.map(function(a) {
        if (a.category.category === res[i]) {
          return a.category.subcategory;
        }
      });
      $scope.categories[i]['subcategories'] 
      $scope.categories[i]['subcategories'] = arrayUnique(result2);
    }        
  });
}

var arrayUnique = function(a) {
  return a.reduce(function(p, c) {
    if (p.indexOf(c) < 0 && c != undefined) p.push(c);
      return p;
  }, []);
};
```

In a way I'm using map/reduce to get the categories and subcategories, but my problem is that with all of these, in my html, the ng-repeat doesn't show anything, as if the $scope.categories is still empty, even we I console.log it I get the following result:

```
{ 0: {category: "category1",
      subcategories: [{subcategory: "sub1"},{subcategory: "sub2"}]
     }, 
  1: {category: "category2",
      subcategories: [{subcategory: "sub1"},{subcategory: "sub2"}]
     }, ...
}
```

EDIT:

when I do the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="category in categories">
  {{category.category}}
  <div ng-repeat="subcategory in category.subcategories">{{subcategory}}</div>
</div>
```

It prints as it should the list of categories and subcategories, the main difference is that I'm using `<div>` instead of `<optgroup> <option>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with materializecss select. It was instantiating before updating `$scope.categories`, which was empty

The solution can be

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('select').material_select();
  $('input.select-dropdown').click(function(e){
    $('select').material_select();
  });
});
```

solves the problem but it's a horrible hack, but I'll be moving to a timeout solution or instantiating after updating `$scope.categories`

Answer (score 0):

If your console.log is accurate then you are using ng-repeat over an object not an array. This is doable but requires special syntax such as:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj"> ... </div>
```

you can find the documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Otherwise, try translating the results into an array before using them in ng-repeat.

As a side note, angular offers the ng-options directive for ng-select. That way you can assign a data model to it instead of hard coding a template.

Comment: yes, it's an object and not an array, I tried 

<optgroup ng-repeat="(key, category) in categories" label="{{category.category}}">

but no success

Comment: I think in your case you would do "($index, category) in categories". "key" is the generic term for how to find the index of the object to render. Otherwise, you could just use the result returned from arrayUnique and replace the strings with objects that have a subcategories property. That way you're using an array not an object. This would probably reduce the work in your code also.